# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with update 4 gives this error when i try to open .webtest

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Cannot open `.webtest` file in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with update 4, it shows

> The Parameter is incorrect.(Exception from HrResult 0x80070057(E_InvalidARG

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?